# Changing a $_POST value that is returned, based on its value

Tags: php

When I `print_r` it returns an array of data.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

My input fields are standard address information and a patient id:

```
Array ( [patient_id] => this [Last] => that [First] => Ted [ADDRESS1] => dey
[DOB] => [email] => [insurance_id] => [Phone] => [State] => CA [Zip] => 91236
[Status] => 3 [select_top] => 17 )
```

For status it's usually going to be entered as a 1, 2, or 3.

- 1 equals Lead
- 2 equals Active
- 3 equals Inactive

How can I change the POST value so when a 3 is entered it's returned as Inactive or 2 returned as Active?

Is it possible to do a `foreach` loop and just change the value to an alias or something?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if($key == '3') $val = Inactive;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with SQL, so the tag is incorrect.

Comment: I removed it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`switch` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). There's no need to use a `foreach` loop:

```
switch($_POST['status']) {
    case 1: $_POST['status'] = 'Lead'; break;
    case 2: $_POST['status'] = 'Active'; break;
    case 3: $_POST['status'] = 'Inactive'; break;
    default: $_POST['status'] = 'Huh?';
}
```

Comment: hehe had the same idea ;) +1

Comment: What if it's part of a class and is constructed like so: 12=>array('account_status'=>'Status') I'm just aliasing it as Status and it's going to return a 1, 2, 3. Does that make any sense or should i post the class?

Comment: @HeadWay - `$_POST['status'] = $aliases[ $_POST['status'] ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than manipulate the `$_POST` super global, I'd rather look up the value from a *known* set of valid entries. For example

```
$statusValues = array(
    1 => 'Lead',
    2 => 'Active',
    3 => 'Inactive'
);

if (!array_key_exists($_POST['status'], $statusValues)) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException($_POST['status']);
}
$status = $statusValues[$_POST['status']];
```

Comment: Thank you Phil and Danny. Cheers!